# What is the data format for a file to be read by Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dataformat, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I've been reading up on Redshift Spectrum and there are a few things I just don't understand.

1. I understand that Redshift Spectrum will read data from files stored in S3, but what is the actual file I need to store in S3?  Is it some SQL statement? can I put it in any format?  Say I run an ecommerce site, do I create one file per order? or one file that has all the orders in it and keep appending to that?
2. Should I still expect a flat format?  Or can I do more NoSQL type things with the data in these files?
3. Everytime I query, is it still getting data from the files?  Meaning, lets say I run query 1... update existing files.. and run the query again.  Will I get different results?  Or has the data already been pulled into spectrum somehow?

Answer (score 2):

From [Creating Data Files for Queries in Amazon Redshift Spectrum - Amazon Redshift](http://docs-aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-data-files.html):

> Redshift Spectrum supports the following structured and semistructured data formats:
>
> - AVRO
> - PARQUET
> - TEXTFILE
> - SEQUENCEFILE
> - RCFILE
> - RegexSerDe
> - Optimized row columnar (ORC)
> - Grok
> - OpenCSV
> - Ion
> - JSON

When using [`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html), you specify an **Amazon S3 bucket and path**. All files in that path (directory) will be included in the query. If a file is added/changed/deleted, then the next time the query is run, the new/modified data will be included because Redshift Spectrum always looks at the files stored in S3.

Amazon Redshift Spectrum is **similar to Amazon Athena**. They both allow you to run SQL queries against files stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.